# QuickTime Screen + Audio Capture

Tags: macos, quicktime, macbook-pro

I'm using Retina Macbook Pro running OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion. Is it possible to use QuickTime to capture both audio and screen ? If not, what are the free apps that can do it?

P.S. A lot of the times I see on Youtube that it possible to capture screen + audio + have a little window of yourself in the corner - how is that achived?

Comment: rMBP = Retina Mac Book Pro. ML = Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it. You may need a pair of headphones if you use the bult-in microphone.

Open quicktime and click File->New Screen Recording 
Select the audio source by clicking on the small down-pointing arrow 
Turn up the sound that appears below the record button 
Click File->New Movie Recoring 
Resize the movie window and place it where you like it 
Click record on the screen recorder window

Comment: This solution does not capture audio.  Quicktime cannot capture audio when you are doing a screen capture.

Comment: This actually can be done with hardware, I just had to do it differently than the answer explained. To screen record WITH internal audio AND microphone voice over using QuickTime on a Mac (without downloading additional software) you will need a USB microphone and a Bluetooth headset + mic'd audio cable. This works even if you only have one audio port on your computer. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkksiIDL5qU

Answer (score 1):

just For the help of others having below OS version 
Mac OS 10.12.5 Sierra

MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015)

Click on Quicktime -> Start new screen recording -> recording screen opens ->Click on down arrow in right side of red button ,Make sure to click it ,you will get option for internal (built in microphone) selection ,select it and you are done .

Answer (score 0):

Soundflower is the free tool for you. Take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJT80qqqIyQ) and [How to record both screen and sound with Quicktime on El Capitan?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212829/how-to-record-both-screen-and-sound-with-quicktime-on-el-capitan)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your P.S.: Picture-in-picture videos are done with third-party software. A free option for this on Mac is [OBS](https://obsproject.com/download), which is primarily intended for live streaming to gaming sites, but does allow offline recording too. In my experience, it can be a little tricky to set up.

Reputable paid options include [Screenflow](http://www.telestream.net/screenflow/overview.htm) and [Camtasia](https://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html), which are far more polished but can only be used for offline recording.

Answer (score -2):

Theres a few youtube videos that show you how to do this (as best it can) with quick time, [heres a good one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wo2-_minLPg).

Quicktime is far from the best screen recording software though, and it won't give you the picture in picture you're looking for. I don't know of any free software that will but [screenflow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/) is one of the most popular paid apps and it's under a hundred bucks so if you want really nice screencasts, take a look at it.

Comment: Your link to youtube is broken.

Answer (score -3):

This is a Youtube video I produced on how to do it entirely for free: record CPU audio as well as Mic Audio while doing a screen capture.  You'd think that it would be a standard feature...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lB9Ovqk5H5c

It should work just fine!

Good Luck

Comment: Can you please summarize the content of the video? It may get removed in the future leading to a broken link here.

Comment: Sound flower is no long maintained.