# Unable to record screen with audio using Soundflower

Tags: audio, screen-capture, quicktime

The answer to  [How to record both screen and sound with Quicktime on El Capitan?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212829/how-to-record-both-screen-and-sound-with-quicktime-on-el-capitan)
 explains what to do in order to record the screen using QuickTime player with sound (both from the micro and the computer).

I followed the steps there, and although I successfully managed to install Soundflower and to add a Multi-Output device, the screen recording produced by QuickTime player has no sound.

Is there a way to check whether the Soundflower works properly?

I'm connected to an Apple display as well, so does this pose an issue?

Comment: You normally have to go into System Preferences > Sound and ensure you select Soundflower (2 channel) in your audio output.

Comment: That doesn't work. In fact, in the mentioned post they say I have to have the output as the multi-output device

Comment: I'm just going based on my own experience of doing just this. I never had to do this multi-output stuff, but my experience of that Audio MIDI Setup application is that it generally doesn't work very well.