# Internal Microphone not available for QuickTime When Screen Recording

Tags: audio, screen-capture, quicktime, microphone

My Mac is Early 2015 MBP with MacOS BigSur.

When I select File -> New Audio Recording option from within QuickTime, I see this

[image]

On the other hand, when I choose File -> New Screen Recroding, I see the following

[image]

In other words, there appears to be no way for me to do a screen recording with internal sound. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to record both screen and sound with Quicktime on El Capitan?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212829/how-to-record-both-screen-and-sound-with-quicktime-on-el-capitan) However, the answers are a bit old and could use some updating.

Comment: @DavidAnderson, I may try one of their suggestions involving `background-music`, but consider this to be an unfavorable option. I should be able to do this without any extra drivers. That is how it was in the past. The Soundflowerbed I have used in the past. It is not supported for BigSur, from what I have gathered at the official repo.

Comment: Your question does have some ambiguity. Your titles states "Not Internal Microphone", but the image shows "Built-in Microphone". Are they not the same thing? On the other hand, I assume you want to record the sound that normal goes to the speakers. Is this true instead?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Built-in mic is the one that is used when I speak on Zoom or something like that. Internal Mic is the system sound, like Youtube or UI sounds. That was my understanding.

Comment: Surely a microphone is an input device - system sound goes on an output device. And ZoomAudiooDevice is what you use on Zoom - so isn't builtin and internal the same thing

Comment: ‘Built-In Microphone’ and ‘Internal Microphone’ refer to the same thing: the microphone in your Mac recording external sound.