# Cannot share video sound in Microsoft Teams using macbook

Tags: ipad, catalina

I've got a macbook running macOS Catalina (latest updates) and I have to use MS Teams for meetings (teams must be used, restrictive environment).

Whenever I Share my screen of anything with sound (youtube video for example), meeting participants can see the video but not hear the sound.

I've found that this is because the teams app for macOS doesn't have the option to share system sounds like the ms teams app for windows.  MS has stated this is coming Q3 (which could be anytime now) https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/32616083-share-video-and-audio-during-meetings but I need an immediate workaround starting tomorrow if possible.

I also have an ipad if I can use that as a workaround some how.

Is there anyway to make this happen?

-Edit1- I have discovered that an old iMac running Sierra (not High Sierra) does not have this problem.  My best guess is that it is likely a Catalina issue (like so many others) but I have no way to confirm it.  Nor do I have anyway to test on Mojave.

Comment: As a workaround, [Jitsi](https://meet.jit.si) is a free and open-source video conference platform that allows you to share a YouTube video link and have everybody stream it simultaneously. [See here](https://youtu.be/AgCpsb_KHuM) for a demo.

Comment: Unfortunately the workaround must use Teams as the meeting platform.

Comment: I don't know if it will work with Teams, but it's worth a look:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/251879/119271

Comment: Maybe you could install Mojave on an external drive to test.

Comment: You may have luck with [Soundflower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/) (download [from GitHub](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower/releases/tag/2.0b2)). I use it for audio redirection in Audacity and other apps successfully, but Skype in particular doesn't seem to like it when I try to use an aggregate input device (system sounds + microphone; it will only do one or the other at any one time), so YMMV with MS Teams.